# How to integrate $- \mu M(t) + \alpha M(t) \exp(-\beta M(t)) \,dt$?

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I want to solve $M$ where $M(t)$ is a function of time $t$. I have this equation,
$$M'(t) = - \mu M(t) + \alpha M(t) e^{-\beta M(t)}$$
where $\alpha, \mu$ and $\beta$ are nonnegative constants. I know that I need to take the integration in order to do so but I do not know how to solve it. I already tried integration by parts but it gives me a much more complicated equation after. Can someone tell me what technique to use?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Amounts to $\int\frac{dx}{x(\alpha e^{-\beta x}-\mu)}$, out of hope for analytic solution.

Comment: Yes. You are correct that they are the same. But can you please tell me how to integrate that? I mean, what technique can I use?

Comment: @Xrylche - "out of hope for analytic solution" means no, metamorphy cannot tell you how to integrate that, except to do so numerically, or by Taylor series.